# Font file not exist while loading front with Expo React Native App

Tags: react-native, expo

all,

I am new to react native, I am now having issue when I was trying to use customize fonts for my application, it keeps giving me error: None of these files exist: * assets\fonts\ARIAL.TTF etc.
I appreciate if anyone can help me, thank you so much.

I am using expo to run my project, and I install expo-font(v 10.0.4) to use costomize font. Here is my code of using the fonts:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import AuthStack from './routes/authStack'
import store, { persistor } from './store'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'
import Loading from './components/loading'

function App() {

  const [fontLoaded] = useFonts({
    Arial: require('./assets/fonts/ARIAL.TTF'),
    ArialBold: require('./assets/fonts/ARIALBD.TTF'),
    BlairMd: require('./assets/fonts/BlairMdITCTTMediumFont.ttf'),
  })
  console.log('app font loaded====', fontLoaded)
  return fontLoaded ? (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <AuthStack />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  ) : (
    <Loading />
  )

}
```

So I am using useFonts hook from expo-font to load my fonts, and I already put my fonts file under assets, here is the file structure:
[assets folder is under the same directory as App.js. In assets folder, there is fonts folder, and in fonts folder, all my fonts files are there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4sUh.png)

If anyone can help me, thank you so much

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it is resolved after stop and rerun the server.

I guess expo server needs to execute again in order changes to take place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did this, but it did not work. Can you be more specific?